# Visualing a Towers of Hanoi Algorithm in Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, algorithm

Latley I am working on a school project and I have to present an algorithm which is in my case a solving algorithm for the puzzle Towers of Hanoi. Due to my knowledge in HTML/CSS I thought it would be quite neat to use those + Javascript to visualise the steps on a webpage.

I got the site set up as well as the basic, recursive algorithm.

```
function move(n, beg, aux, end) {

if (n == 1) {
    console.log(beg + '-->' + end + '\n');
    setTowers(beg, end);
} else {
    move(n - 1, beg, end, aux);
    move(1, beg, aux, end);
    move(n - 1, aux, beg, end);
    }
}
```

Layout of the page (CSS code wont help here):

```
section#main-app
.app-wrapper
    .tower-wrapper
        .tower#twr--a
            .block.blck--top
            .block.blck--middle
            .block.blck--bottom
        .tower#twr--b
            .block.blck--top
            .block.blck--middle
            .block.blck--bottom
        .tower#twr--c
            .block.blck--top
            .block.blck--middle
            .block.blck--bottom
```

Then I started to struggle as I had to somehow visualise it. I thought of putting each tower into an array:

```
var twrElemsA = document.getElementById('twr--a').getElementsByClassName('block');
towerA = jQuery.makeArray(twrElemsA);
```

Then the function to actually set the color. 2 things for the moment: It wont erase the color if needed and it wont set the color at all because I messed up the switch statement/dont know how to proper do it.

```
function setColors(target) {

target.forEach(function (element) {

    switch (element) {
        case '<div class="block blck--top">':
            $(element).css({
                'background-color': 'red'
            });
            break;

        case '<div class="block blck--middle">':
            $(element).css({
                'background-color': '#51616F'
            });
            break;

        case '<div class="block blck--bottom">':
            $(element).css({
                'background-color': '#394B5A'
            });
            break;
    }

});
```

}

Now, if the move function returns for example A --> B, setColors should then iterate over TowerB and set the background-colors of all three blocks to a specific color. But the switch statement does not work and I run out of ideas and time which is a devasting combo.

Maybe someone knows what could help here. I appreciate any help!

Regards..

Comment: Your switch won't work because you're comparing elements to strings. Instead, you could consider using an `if-else` and check if a class exists: `$(element).hasClass('blck--top')`.

Answer (score 1):

From the look of your setColors function you are making visual modifications to the blocks using JavaScript. The general consensus in front end web development is to leave those tasks to CSS.

In your case you are checking of your DIVs have the classes `block` and `blck--bottom`. So rather than using JavaScript perhaps you could attempt a stylesheet with the following selector:

```
.block.blck--top {
    background-color: '#51616F';
}

.block.blck--middle {
    background-color: '#51616F';
}

.block.blck--bottom {
    background-color: '#51616F';
}
```

In contrast to this however, if you need to perform further actions that are not visual based you can take on the following approach.

```
function setColors(target) {

target.forEach(function (element) {

    if(element.classList.contains('blck--top'))
    {
        element.style['background-color'] = 'red';
        /* - Extra code here - */
    }
    else if(element.classList.contains('blck--middle'))
    {
        element.style['background-color'] = '#51616F';
        /* - Extra code here - */
    }
    else if(element.classList.contains('blck--bottom'))
    {
        element.style['background-color'] = '#394B5A';
        /* - Extra code here - */
    }
});
```

But if you really wish to use switch case statements then:

```
function setColors(target) {

target.forEach(function (element) {

    switch (element.getAttribute('class')) {
        case 'block blck--top':
            $(element).css({
                'background-color': 'red'
            });
            break;

        case 'block blck--middle':
            $(element).css({
                'background-color': '#51616F'
            });
            break;

        case 'block blck--bottom':
            $(element).css({
                'background-color': '#394B5A'
            });
            break;
    }
});
```

Please note that I have also provided a way for you perform the same tasks using plain old JavaScript (JQuery-less if you will).